# Problems with pointers to a struct sockaddr_in in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, sockaddr-in

I came across some problems when accessing a `struct sockaddr_in*` (socket C lib type).

Considering the following function:

```
void f(struct sockaddr_in* in){
  /* Some networking operations. */
  in->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  in->sin_port = htons(PORT);
  in->sin_family = AF_INET;
}
```

This code doesn't work (segmentation fault):

```
int main(){
  struct sockaddr_in* s;
  f(s);
}
```

While this one works:

```
int main(){
  struct sockaddr_in s;
  f(&s);

  // Likewise does:
  struct sockaddr_in s;
  struct sockaddr_in* p;
  p = &s;
  f(p);
}
```

Why does this happens?

Comment: In the first case, what does `s` point to?

Comment: There's no reason to use `malloc()` here, and several good reasons not to (heap allocations are relatively expensive, and invite memory leaks).  Declaring a `struct sockaddr_in` on the stack and passing in a pointer to it is preferred.

Comment: @dbush To nothing, I had a completely irrational thought...

Comment: @SupportUkraine That's just right. In fact, it's just normal it can't refer to a "non-existing" variable. It works with the malloc() instead.

Comment: And the reason is explained well by @JeremyFriesner, surely you all agree with your answers, they're linked. Great, thank you!

Comment: No need to talk about sockaddr_in - you could have the exact same problem with int

Comment: @user253751 Yes, it is.